# In how many ways can a cube be oriented?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can a cube be oriented?

My attempt:

Imagine that there are eight points in space which must be occupied by the vertices of the cube. Let $A$ be one of these points. Fix any one of the vertices at $A$. This can be done in 8 ways.

We have three different choices for an adjacent point (say $B$), because each vertex of a cube is connected to three other vertices.

Once A and B (being adjacent points) are determined, the other points are automatically determined. (Is this true? If so, how would I prove it?) As such, we have $8 \cdot 3 = 24$ orientations.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. You can also look at it this way: first choose one of the six planes to be shown *to the front*, then choose one of the four remaining planes to be shown *to the top*. As such, the number of orientations equals:

$$6 \cdot 4 = 24$$

Note that the number of orientations is technically infinite, but you are of course referring to the $24$ possible orientations where the perpendicular to each of the six planes is parallel with one of the $x$-, $y$- and $z$-axes.